# Test a GCD block as the async process is taking some time

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I am developing an app that contacts a RESTful server to get some data and then with the returned JSON response to display that data.

Using UniRest calls and all is working well. The main call is 'runUnirestRequest'

The uni rest call is an async GCD dispatch call. My problem is that because I am testing locally the call is so quick I can't see the activity indicator rolling. It simply disappears before I can see it.

The GCD block occur within the viewController viewDidLoad call.

What I need to achieve: Have the async unirest call take several seconds to simulate a server response that is slow (Dont want to actually stop the iOS app in its tracks).

Please excuse any coding errors/bad habits, only been doing objective c for a week but am happy for any additional constructive crit. :)

I have tried

```
sleep(5); // But bad idea as far as I can see.
```

Also tried

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0]; // but this doesn't seem to do anything.
```

viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createActivityIndicator];

    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad->thread: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    [messageLabel setText:@""];

    unirestQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.simpleweb.pbs.dayDataUnirestRequest", NULL);

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    daySalesFigures = [[PBSDaySales alloc] init];
    responseVal = [[HttpJsonResponse alloc] init];

    // Use Grand Central Dispatch to run async task to server
    dispatch_async(unirestQueue, ^{
        [self runUnirestRequest:self.requestUrl];

    });

    dispatch_after(unirestQueue, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    });
}
```

runUniRestRequest function

```
- (void) runUnirestRequest:(NSString*)urlToGet
{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];

    NSLog(@"runUnirestRequest called");

    HttpJsonResponse* response = [[Unirest get:^(SimpleRequest* request) {
        [request setUrl:@"http://x.x.x.x:9000/Sales/Day/2013-02-14"];
    }] asString];

    NSString *jsonStr = [response body];

    SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];

    id response2 = [jsonParser objectWithString:jsonStr];
    [self deserializeJsonPacket:(NSDictionary*)response2];

}
```

Comment: Just a note: Unirest is just a wrapper around a `NSURLConnection` utilizing solely the _synchronous convenient_ method `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`. An this even without respecting a possibly error. Albeit the API is quite appealing, the implementation - in contrast - is questionable. I would hope, the implementation would be improved. So, you are a bit limited for now with a suboptimal implementation: no error handling, no real async approach, no custom authentication, no large data bodies, ... and a couple more No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dispatch_after`'s first parameter is time. You are passing in `unirestQueue`, which is `dispatch_queue_t` queue according to

```
unirestQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.simpleweb.pbs.dayDataUnirestRequest", NULL);
```

proper code for `dispatch_after`, i.e. performing block after some delay, is like this:

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //  Do whatever you want
});
```

Edit: Oh, I probably see what you are trying to accomplish :-) You thought the `dispatch_after` means "do something after this queue" right? Nope, it's "do something after some time"

Edit 2: You can use code like below to do something time consuming in background and update UI when its done

```
//  Start block on background queue so the main thread is not frozen
//  which prevents apps UI freeze
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //  Do something taking a long time in background
    //  Here we just freeze current (background) thread for 5s
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];

    //  Everything in background thread is done
    //  Call another block on main thread to do UI stuff
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //  Here you are in the main thread again
        //  You can do whatever you want
        //  This example just stops UIActivityIndicatorView
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    });
});
```

Edit 3: I recommend [this great article about GCD at raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial) for more detailed info

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly. I don't fully understand the GCD threading in the code you gave so going to have to break it down and understand how it works, but thank you.

One question I did have was this: Is running the Unirest async call within GCD pointless? Is it not the same to run an sync unirest call inside the GCD block?

Thanks again Lukas you were a great help.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I helped you. Well, I hoped my code is commented enough :-) To your question: I don't know how Unirest works. But basically: if its synced request (blocking - following code lines wait until its done), you should run it in background thread (in `dispatch_async` block). If it is async (runs itself on bg thread and have success callback), there is no need to call it in another thread at all as it will run in background thread whatsoever